# A Swift/iOS Class Equivalent to Android Dialog?

Tags: android, ios, swift, android-dialog

If I want to create a pop up view in Android, say on clicking a button, a QR code will pop up and things behind will be blurred a bit, I called the Dialog class in Android/Java, which I think is more like a View in iOS.

May I know whether there is a class which is almost equivalent in iOS? I googled around and seems no one mention about that. While some might say I could use AlertController, I would say the experience is completely different. Dialog in Android can contain everything - text, buttons, images, layouts, you name it, while AlertController in iOS is literally just the alert and it does not expect you to do so much customization.

Can anyone illustrate the road ahead for me?

Comment: Well you can simply implement your own DialogController

Comment: You can present any viewcontroller modally and get a similar experience, but it will be an almost fullscreen presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You use `UIAlertController` in Swift.

### Example

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "My Message", preferredStyle: .alert)


            alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blue //Change this or remove


            //Blur Effect

            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
            let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

            blurVisualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds

            self.view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView) //Add the blur effect to the dialog

            //Set Image   
         
            var myImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 89, y: 35, width: 95, height: 80))
            myImage.image = UIImage(named: "MyImage")!

            alertController.view.addSubview(myImage)

            //Button actions

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive) {_ in
                        
                    blurVisualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()

            }
                    
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {_ in

                    blurVisualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
                        
            }

            //Height constraint handler

            var height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(

                item: alertController.view, attribute: 
                   NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,

                relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil,

                attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height,
               
                //Change this as desired

                multiplier: 1, constant: self.view.frame.height * 0.4) 
            
             alertController.view.addConstraint(height) //Set the constraint
                   

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
                   
             

            //Display (present) the alertcontroller

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        }
```

### Result

[image: Result]

### Breaking This Down

- Declare the `alertController`. Set the title to `"My Title"` and the message.
- Set the `tintColor`. This changes it to custom colors other than the default iOS blue tint.
- Add the `UIBlurEffect`. "Tries" to mimic Androids `AlertDialog`. :)
- Declare and add the `UIImageView` to the `alertController` as a sub view
- Add the action buttons. `cancelAction` and `okAction`. Notice the `style:` property? This allows you to choose between `.destructive`, and `.default`. `.destructive` makes the button red-tinted, and `.default` leaves it as the `alertController`'s `tintColor`.
- Add a height constraint. Useful if you want more content visible (like `UIImageViews`)
- Use the `alertController.addAction` functions to add our buttons, and `present` it.
- Extra note: All of this is contained inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`. This is useful if you want to show your dialog before the parent `ViewController` is fully loaded. (E.G. You show your dialog in the `.viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: hi @Omega_Pixel thanks and i will try that. whether it will be visually appealing or not I guess I have to try first. but i didnt think of using alertcontroller with so much customization before. will try and thanks!

Comment: Yes, @BoscoTsin, `UIAlertControllers`are very extensible once you figure out their nuances. Definitely not the fanciness and robustness of Android's `AlertDialogs`, but it works.